# Allow linking to draft documentation Examples

Tags: feature-request, documentation, hyperlinks, draft

While writing a new Topic for documentation, I'm making several Examples.

> ## Feature foo
>
> ### Method bar
>
> You can use foo.bar for such and such.
>
> ### Method baz
>
> You can use foo.baz for something else.
>
> However, if P=NP, you may want to consider using [foo.bar](???)

I want to cross-reference one Example from another. However, there is no "Share" link yet, and I see no way of guessing what the URL will be when the topic/change is approved.

**Feature proposal:** While in draft stage, Examples within a Topic should already have URLs one can use to cross-reference them. They may be automagically rewritten when changes are approved.